# How to change title of individual GLMakie window?

Tags: julia

This is a long shot but here goes...

GLMakie can create multiple figure windows:

```
display( GLMakie.Screen(), fig )
```

Is there a way to set individual figure window titles analogous to what MATLAB does?

```
figure( 'Name', 'My Figure' )
```

To be clear, I am not asking about the axis title.  This is the title of the OS window that shows up in the window decorations and in whatever task manager your OS uses.  I see in [Makie documentation](https://docs.makie.org/stable/documentation/backends/glmakie/) that a window title can be passed in `screen_config` when running `GLMakie.activate!()` but this isn't window-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way pretty much as soon as I posted this but it's a bit of a hack.  Running `activate!( title="whatever" )` does not affect existing windows so it can be used to set the title of an individual GLMakie plot window by running it prior to `display` like this

```
GLMakie.activate!( title = "1st Window" )
display( GLMakie.screen(), fig1 )
GLMakie.activate!( title = "2nd Window" )
display( GLMakie.screen(), fig2 )
```